# Having trouble filling a vector in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am having trouble filling a specified vector with search-values from the spotifyr package and I can't really understand where it is going wrong.

```
top2017id <- numeric(200)

for(i in top2017vec){
  search <- search_spotify(i, type = "track", limit = 1)
  top2017id[i] <- search$id
}

Error in top2017id[i] <- search$id : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `id`.
```

top2017vec is a vector containing 200 track names, for example: "Mi Gente", and what I want the for-loop to do, is search for the first track name in the vector using the search_spotify function, save it to the un-defined "search" and then save search$id to the first place in the already defined vector top2017id, and then repeat the process but with the second track name instead.

The function that I use inside the for-loop, "search_spotify" is a function from the spotifyr package, that returns a list with 27 variables. I have tested outside the for-loop, and indexing with search$id works perfectly fine in returning just a string with the tracks id.

Other than the error I recive, it do add some values to the top2017id vector. The first 200 values are 0, but after it adds 27 values which alternates between a track-name from the top2017vec, and the specific tracks id. Like this:

```
> top2017id
                                                                        
                                                                    "0" 
                                                                        
                                                                    "0" 
                                                                        
                                                                    "0" 
                                                                        
                                                                    "0" 

                                                                    ...

                                                               Believer 
                                               "0pqnGHJpmpxLKifKRmU6WP" 
                                                          Felices los 4 
                                               "1RouRzlg8OKFeqc6LvdxmB"
```

What is it that I have managed to screw up?

Edit:

I kept on trying after the answer from @Dylan_Gomes and I made some progress, however I am stuck with another simillar error now.

```
for(i in 1:length(top2017vec)){
  search <- search_spotify(top2017vec[i], type = "track", limit = 1)
  top2017id[i] <- search$id
}
```

It now works for the first 26 id's, but after the first 26 ids it gives me 0's for the rest of the vector, and then ends. The error message I receive is:

```
Error in top2017id[i] <- search$id : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `id`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your for loop might be the problem. For example:

```
vect<-numeric(200)
for(i in vect){
  search<-rnorm(1,0,1)
  vect[i]<-search
}

vect
```

Doesn't work, it returns a vector of 200 zeros still. Yet, if we change the for loop structure to:

```
for(i in 1:length(vect)){
  search<-rnorm(1,0,1)
  vect[i]<-search
}

vect

  [1]  0.87096868  0.78146593  0.72339698  0.45954073  1.29507907  0.28822357 -0.97277289 -0.22033080
  [9] -0.41323427 -1.79971088 -0.20233652 -1.30564552  0.46676890 -0.64209630  0.95616195  0.67121680
 [17] -0.18220987 -0.45524523 -0.91059605 -1.65350181 -0.33524219  2.60902403  0.58630848 -1.22887993
```

It then works as expected. There might be a different problem going on with `spotifyr` but I can't check it because it doesn't work with the current version of R.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!

You are probably right, however, I believe I would face a problem with getting the seach function to search for the specifik track name, as in the for-loop I have created, I specified it to seach for "i". I may be completely lost however?

the term I search for would in this case just be 1, 2, 3 etc. instead of the track name.

Comment: for example, if i run this code:

``` 
for(i in 1:length(top2017vec)){
  search <- search_spotify(i, type = "track", limit = 1)
  top2017id[i] <- search$id
}
```

it gives me the error

```
Error in search_spotify(i, type = "track", limit = 1) : 
  "q" must be a string
``` 

But maybe there is a better solution to have it autofill the track name?

Comment: in the help docs, q = Search query keywords and optional field filters and operators. That is, this is what you are searching in spotify. `numeric(200)` is a bunch of zeros, not a character string that can be searched in Spotify. Does that make sense? Where are your track names?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense! My track names is in the "top2017vec", a vector with 200 different strings with the track names. I edited my original post and ellaborated a bit more after having tested your solution. It was absolutley some progress, however it now stops after giving me the 26 first ids.

Comment: does `search$id` return one value or a vector?

Comment: it returns a vector. looking like this for example: [1] "5Vr5VijumScTUj9DVUMLmp"

Comment: That is only one value, which is a string, but not a vector. Are `top2017vec` and `top2017id` the same length?

Comment: Oh, I might be mistaken then? when I test and run is.vector(test) where test is where I have saved search$id, it gives TRUE. And yes, both are of length 200.

Comment: Hmm, so a vector of length 1?  It is difficult to trouble-shoot without running the code myself, but I am wondering if replacing `top2017id[i] <- search$id` with `top2017id[i] <- search$id[1]` would help.

Comment: I believe that I have found what causes the problem, it seems like the 27th track string, does not give an output from the seach. And for some reason it does not seem to continue when it reaches that error. It doesnt seem to like to seach for that specific remix of despacito! I will try to manually change that trackname and see if it solves the problem!

Comment: I see. perhaps the string doesn't exist in spotify. You could check that by running just that one separately and see if you still get no output / an error

Comment: So, I tested again and it did solve the problem. It works perfect now. I appriciate you taking the time to help me. Thank you!